# How to access a specific list item from a join in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the current working setup and using Ansible 2.3:

```
environment_vars_docmosis_hosts: "{{ groups['role_ccm_docmosis'] | intersect(groups ['stack_' ~ stack]) }}"
```

Which resolves to two hostnames: hostname1 and hostname2

I am trying to extract the only hostname1 from the above.

When I try using `environment_vars_docmosis_hosts.0` or `environment_vars_docmosis_hosts[0]` from this expression:

```
_docmosis_pool_config: "{{ (environment_vars_docmosis_hosts[0] | default(['localhost'])) | join(':2100,') }}:2100"
```

I only get the first character of the hostname

What would be a proper way of accessing the first hostname ?

Comment: I guess one of the issues is to establish what format environment_vars_docmosis_hosts are generated as based on the above

Comment: Possibly. What would be Ansible's structure output from: environment_vars_docmosis_hosts: "{{ groups['role_ccm_docmosis'] | intersect(groups ['stack_' ~ stack]) }}" ? Can this not be established without a debug print ? And how can I debug print not inside a playbook ?

Comment: Might be something I'm doing however 
debug:
  msg: "TEST"
  var: environment_vars_docmosis_hosts

Doesn't bring anything up in the console and i'm running with -vvv ?

Comment: I did see that. I'm seeing plenty of output in the console just not that specific debug print...

Comment: just keep the task needed or save the output in a file and search the name of task debug zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz  as i have done in the answer

Answer (score 1):

to debug:

```
- name: debug zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
  debug:
    msg: "{{ (environment_vars_docmosis_hosts[0] | d('localhost')) ~ ':2100' }}"
```

Comment: Don't think that'll work from a group_vars file where key value pairs are expected

Comment: display the content of your inventory..

Comment: Right, here's the output for the debug message above (I've masked the real hostnames): [u'hostname1', u'hostname2'] And I need to extract hostname1 String from it

Comment: So, environment_vars_docmosis_hosts[0] works if I just output it as is, I think the problem is that I try to join it with the port (see original statement)

Comment: difficcult to follow you... in this case just show the result you want..

Comment: :) Think I got this. Need half an hour and might close this question. Regardless thank you for your time so far !!

Answer (score 0):

The join above was wrong.

This works: environment_vars_docmosis_hosts[0] | default(['localhost'])}}:2100"

Comment: dont forget to close your question by validating your or my answer

Comment: Will do when SE allows it ! :)